Rigged Multires Mesh: Any way to solve lighting artifacts at low-res base mesh's polygon edges?
So I have a mesh that has a multires modifier on it that I wanted to rig for posing purposes (the mesh was originally sculpted into a T-pose)
Overall, I'm happy with the results but I've noticed that the model has some strange lighting artifacts on the polygon edges of the low resolution mesh.

I've since learned that this is an expected behaviour of the modifier (from what I could find on the internet) and I would presume it has to do with how the high resolution mesh's weights are not interpolated from the lower res mesh (though this would be a nice feature, if there are any devs out there.)
However, for the sake of rendering this out quickly, I'd prefer to work around this somehow so I can finish this project and keep this limitation in mind for my next project.
Does anyone out there have any relatively quick fixes for a problem like this? I would even accept a suggestion for how to quickly take all of the posed multi-res modified meshes and quickly make a render-only high quality mesh that transfers the weights from the low rigged low res meshes.
